# MongoDB checking if insert or update was successfull with async await

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, async-await, nosql

I have this mongo DB update query with async await:

```
var result = await db
          .collection("threads")
          .updateOne(
            { _id: ObjectId(thread_id) },
            { $push: { messages: messageObject } }
          )
```

I need to send the success or failure result of this query back to client, how do I find if an `update` or `insert` was successful and take another action based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`updateOne` returns `UpdateWriteOpResult` which is in the form of:

```
{
    result: { ok: number; n: number; nModified: number };
    connection: any;
    matchedCount: number;
    modifiedCount: number;
    upsertedCount: number;
    upsertedId: { _id: ObjectId };
}
```

So check for `result.result.ok` to see if the query went through proper. you can also view `result.result.n` to see if it matched any documents and `result.result.nModified` to see if the update changed the document.

`insertOne` returns `InsertOneWriteOpResult` which is in the form of:

```
{
  insertedCount: number;
  ops: TSchema[];
  insertedId: TSchema['_id'];
  connection: any;
  result: { ok: number; n: number };
}
```

And again you can check `result.result.ok` to see if it went through.

You can find all method signatures [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongodb/index.d.ts)

*This post is relevant for Mongo's `nodejs` driver.